# Android:How to extract siblings information onItemClick

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have implemented CustomAdapter using ViewHolder. I am listening to the onclick event on item of List View with the following method

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                }               
            });
```

How can I access the description test field ?

The following is the xml which is instantiated by the adapter

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
     >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:textColor="#cccccc"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:textColor="#cccccc"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you try the below? is it working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

             TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
             String value = tv.getText().toString();
             TextView desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
             String descp = desc.getText().toString();

            }               
        });
```

In `onItemClick` you can use the view object to initialize views. Then get the value from textview.

The second way use

```
  parent.getItemAtPosition(position); // this is better
```

Here you will use the adapterview (parent) and get the item at that postion

Example :

```
 HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap<String,String> parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
 // assuming you are populating data using hashmap in your case might be different
```

Then

```
 String title = map.get("key");
```

Comment: thanks for providing the answer . . But I observed strange thing the object which I used for making the listview has 4 attributes . .I set one attribute as visible , another as invisible but duing the access I all four attributes available to me.. It kind of lessened my work :)